# How to store large data in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

My app needs lots of data to display inside the flutter app offline. Previously I stored all the data in List format and looped through them to display items inside app but those data became very huge and exceeded more than 1000 lines and 100KB so I was wondering if it was fine or is there more efficient way to store data inside the app?

Lists Format I used:

```
const List<String> summaries = [
    "Lots of texts",
    "Another Lots of texts",
     // Lots of other large items
]

const List QnA = [
  [
    {
      'question':'My question?',
      'answer':"""My Answer""",
    },
    {
      'question':'My question?',
      'answer':"""My Answer""",
    }
]
// Lots of list items
];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use database in your app

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite - sqflite for large data

Comment: he is talking about the preset data...not the sqlite thing..he is adding large set of data inside app.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer converting allthose data's to a json format and place it inside asset folder and decoding it.

```
final data = rootBundle.loadString('assets/text_asset/data.json');

json.decode(data);
```